# Taleo asks for an incumbent when importing an open requisition with TCC

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

I want to use Taleo Connect Client to create an open requisition in Taleo. If a requisition's status is set to draft when importing, it will be created successfully. However, if I try to open the requisition by setting `State,Description` as "To Be Approved" or "Approved", it will fail with the following message:

> The following fields must be filled before the requisition is saved: Is there an incumbent?.;

Normally incumbents aren't required when creating a requisition. In fact, as far as I can tell, TCC doesn't have a field for incumbents.

Why is TCC asking me if there is an incumbent when I try to import an open requisition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field "Is there an incumbent?." is a custom field and these fields are not visible in TCC unless you synchronize them. To complete the synchronization you need to click on "Product Integration Pack" in the top right corner of the right pane. You will see an icon with a person on it (Synchronize custom fields).

[image]

If you click on it, you will be asked to provide the product and version, make sure to select the same version as your requisition import script.

The error you are getting is surely caused by the custom field configuration. Some of the fields are required to save a requisition and that custom field must be required to approve it. Look for the field configuration, you will find a drop-down list indicating if the field is required:

[image]

To get rid of the error, you have 2 options:

- Add the field to your import script
- Modify the field configuration to make it not required

Comment: Good catch. The field was set to "Required for approval" in Taleo. I had trouble finding it as TCC uses the Field Name, but the error message used the Field Label.